# Почему не работает multitouch?

Tags: java, android, drag-n-drop, multi-touch

На экране элементы ImageView и SeekBar. одновременно нужно двигать оба элемента: менять значение seekbar и перемещать imageView.

[image: На экране элементы ImageView и SeekBar]

Работает только первое касание. Когда касаюсь ImageView на второе касание не реагирует seekbar. Почему?

```
OnTouchListener onTch = new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {   // индекс касания
            int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
            ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder dsb = new View.DragShadowBuilder(imV);
            // событие
            int actionMask = event.getActionMasked();

            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {// первое касание

                Log.e(TAG,"Down");
                return true;
            }

            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){// последующие касания

                Log.e(TAG,"ACTION_POINTER_DOWN");
                return true;

            }         

            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){// движение

                Log.e(TAG,"Move");
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.imageView:
                        Log.d(TAG, "v.getId=" + v.getId());
                        Log.d(TAG, "R.id.imageView=" + R.id.imageView);

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startDragAndDrop1");
                            v.startDragAndDrop(clipData, dsb, v, 0);
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startDragAndDrop2");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startDragAndDrop3");
                            v.startDrag(clipData, dsb, v, 0);
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startDragAndDrop4");
                        }
                        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "1234");
                        break;
                    case R.id.seekBar:
                        //тут что писать?
                        break;

                }
                return true;
            }

                return false;
        }

    };
```

Код Seekbar:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
{
    String val_seekBar=String.valueOf(100+seekBar.getProgress());
    mTextView.setText(val_seekBar);
}
```

А когда вместо элемента ImageView добавляю кнопки, тогда все правильно работает. Можно не отпуская кнопку менять значения seekBar`а.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // событие
    int actionMask = event.getActionMasked();
    // индекс касания
    int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
    // число касаний
    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
    switch (actionMask) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // первое касание
            inTouch = true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // последующие касания
            downPI = pointerIndex;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // прерывание последнего касания
            inTouch = false;
            tx1.setText("0");
            tx2.setText("0");
            tx3.setText("0");
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // прерывания касаний
            upPI = pointerIndex;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button:
                    tx1.setText("Нажата кнопка Button1");
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    tx2.setText("Нажата кнопка Button2");
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]